# Back-propagation until the input layer in neural network

Tags: neural-network

I have a question regarding neural networks back-propagation. Suppose we have a trained DNN for some data. Then we feed a corrupted data into NN and back-propagate the error not until the first hidden layer, but until the input layer (so to say we calculate deltas for the input neurons).  Does the error term shows us a mismatch between "clean" and "corrupted" vector?

Comment: First why you wanna do that?

Comment: What are "clean" and "corrupted" supposed to mean here?

Comment: Just came up with the same idea, trying to use BP on DNN to construct a valid input from a corrupted input sample and a known output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting the question correctly, you have two input vectors i1 = (a, b, ...) and i2 = (c, d, ...). You then have two corresponding output vectors o1 = (v, w, ...) and o2 = (x, y, ...).

i1 is part of your valid training data and is used to teach the NN the model. After this is done, you want to use the NN to detect the delta between the invalid o2 and the valid output given a correct application of the model to i2?

If this is the case, train the NN as normal with all of your valid input cases, then feed your test cases (input vectors which correspond to known corrupted output vectors) and collect the results *with backpropagation disabled*. That is, once the NN has learned the correct model, stop training and simply compare the "clean" results to the corrupted results yourself.

Note: You could alternatively train a neural network to accept as input a set of values corresponding to the input of some other process and a set of values corresponding to the (possibly corrupted) output of that process and produce as output the difference between the clean values and the corrupted values, but the extra training and framing of the data just to avoid doing the subtraction yourself is probably not worth it.